# Visual Studio Code keeps giving me indent or syntax errors when executing if statements?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, syntax, indentation

```
loc = 'Bank'

if loc == 'Auto Shop':
    print("Cars are cool!")
elif loc == 'Bank':
    print('Money is cool!')
elif loc == 'Store':
    print('Welcome to the store!')
else:
    print("I do not know much.")
```

I'm trying to revise some beginner level Python and have been using Visual Studio Code (on Mac) for my scripts. Whenever I try to run blocks of code such as the if statement above, I get error codes like `"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"` and `"IndentationError: unexpected indent"`. Tried doing my indentation over again and checked my indentation in Sublime and it was fine. The code also runs in my terminal.

I think something is up with my VSC, it's running Python 3.8 which is what I used in my Mac terminal to run the code just fine, but is acting funky when using its terminal.

This is bothering me as it means I might need to switch editors for when I do more complicated stuff later.

Any help would be well appreciated.

Comment: Some IDEs do not like a combination of spaces and tabs. I know with Sublime Text 3, you can highlight all the code and choose to convert whitespace into tabs or spaces, so it's consistent throughout.

Comment: You should add the full traceback for those errors to your question. This will indicate the line of code it is occurring on.

Comment: Always share the entire error message(s).

Comment: set VSC to show you the whitespace so you can see if you use tabs and spaces

Comment: I believe I'm seeing this issue as well, if I remove the elif the issue stops, but that's obviously not what I want

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending this line-by-line then you could get into a situation where your code doesn't line up with what the REPL is expecting.

I'll also say you can simplify your code a bit if you want to make it more flexible:

```py
loc = 'Bank'
messages = {"Auto Shop": "Cars are cool!", "Bank": "Money is cool!", "Store": "Welcome to the store!"}
print(messages.get(loc, "I do not know much."))
```